# How is this question not "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076342/what-features-are-not-available-in-intellij-idea-community-edition-vs-webstorm-f

I just failed a close vote audit for voting to close it.   It's almost nothing to do with programming, and almost entirely opinion based.   If we look at the answers we see "In my eyes, the main difference is...".   What's that if it's not opinion based?

Comment: I'm not sure why you failed the audit, so I'll decline to answer, but I do think that question is off-topic. It's asking for a list of missing features, so it should be closed as "too broad."

Comment: I failed the audit because (I was told) voting to close this question was the wrong thing to do.   Ostensibly, this is an example of a question that is perfectly fine.   That's what I came here to check up on: really??

Comment: You won't fail the same audit again...

Comment: I'd have voted to close from the title alone. Having read everything here, I still would (except it's not possible to vote to close when you can only see the title).

Comment: This metaquestion is lacking a link to the review. You can find a link to the review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history

Comment: I'm not sure what everyone can see, but here is the link I can obtain from @kasperd 's link https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8044215

Comment: The element of the original question that made it appear to me to be too broad and opinion-based is "what are the biggest distinctions between WebStorm && IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition for the Dart workflow?".   This is a broad qualitative question.

Comment: @Will ... actually, I would.   Based on the feedback here, and the resulting action, I have not recalibrated my judgement, but rather had it reinforced as "in line with stackoverflow policy".

Comment: @GreenAsJade With that link I can see that you failed the audit by voting to close, and that the question is deleted. Users with enough reputation will also be able to see what the question was. But you won't fail the same audit again, because when a deleted question shows up in an audit in the close queue, you are supposed to vote to close it. So if the same question does show up in an audit again, then you will pass if you vote to close. Sometimes the audits are just wrong, and it seems people just learn to live with that.

Comment: Hah - I thought we were talking about "the same _kind_ of question", not the exact same question :D :D

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think I have seen one question show up in an audit more than once. And I certainly have seen questions on which I voted previously show up in audits. (And trying to close as duplicate when I recognize that the "new" question showing up in the audit is identical to one I saw last week is not going to work.)

Comment: Funny - I see @Will was referring to the fact that I would vote the same way again, and this time pass, since the question is closed/deleted now.   Well, I learned something about how the audits work!

Comment: @GreenAsJade Exactly!  I'm with you, btw.  How audits are chosen is deeply flawed imho. Audits should be OBVIOUS.  Not borderline cases.

Answer (score 39):

> What's that if it's not opinion based?

I don't know... "A question about a programming tool" maybe?

I gotta confess, I don't use Dart. And I'm not a big fan of IntelliJ. But I'm *pretty sure* that the features available in an IDE do not depend heavily on the subjective opinions of the user. Maybe things are different in the Microsoft world, but Visual Studio 2008 never managed to cough up a good SQL editor, no matter how often I closed my eyes and ***believed***...

So it's a boring question about editor features, scoped to a specific pair of editors and a specific language. Unless you happen to notice everyone eschewing feature comparisons in favor of posting opinionated rants in the answers, I don't see how you can claim this is "opinion-based" much less *primarily* so.

*That said*... That doesn't necessarily make it a good question. Feature-comparison questions often suffer from other problems:

- Duplicating information already available elsewhere in a more comprehensive format.
- Becoming woefully out of date.
- Being entirely too broad for anyone to answer completely.

These have all been issues for, for instance, Visual Studio releases, which tend to be massive (covering multiple languages and a plethora of associated tooling), can change in key areas during and after the final release, and are usually documented more completely in official changelogs and release documentation anyway.

However, I'm not sure those concerns apply here *either* - again, we're talking about editors for *Dart*, not sprawling multilingual development systems.

Unless you observe these problems emerging, I wouldn't be overly concerned about this question at this point.

Comment: The problem is that this has a clickbait potential and an abuse potential since it's about two competing editors with money involved. It's also like "framework vs. framework" questions and is likely to go really outdated really fast.

Comment: I do think it would make a pretty solid blog post though, on the author's website. That would give it timely context.

Comment: While this matter seems largely resolved, I feel a bit compelled to point out that the quote that you re-quoted was from an answer, not the question.   It was demonstrating that the question was already drawing opinionated answers.   I think that this answer makes the point that one shouldn't be too concerned about whether this question stays or goes - it possibly didn't warrant a close vote in the first place.  While that's a fair point, it doesn't help in answering whether or not "Close" should have been a failing selection under audit, which is what this meta question is about.

Answer (score 3):

> "This question has been removed for reasons of moderation ..."

If you like you can feel vindicated, however to be able to answer the question requires the knowledge that IntelliJ IDEA is the "all languages" flavour of JetBrains' IDE and WebStorm is their JavaScript IDE containing a subset of the IntelliJ IDEA features but optimised for JavaScript developers.

If you knew that then you probably shouldn't have closed the question. If you didn't know that then you probably should have skipped the question and if you suspected it was an audit question then you probably should have skipped it too because there is no way of guessing what the audit question was chosen to test for.

In my opinion you were correctly caught closing a question without applying an appropriate level of knowledge.

Comment: Did you get to see the body of the question before it was closed?   If so, in your opinion, did it seek opinions, or facts?    I thought it was an opinion based question about software tools (deserving closing) rather than a factual qustion about software tools (which is on topic).

Comment: I did see the question before it was closed. At the time I thought it was the latter but I can't go back to check the precise wording in its removed state. Either way, it was asking something of interest to a professional or enthusiast programmer working in that area. If in, your view, it did not meet the criteria for a "good question", in my view the appropriate action was either to improve it or leave it for someone else with the requisite knowledge of IntelliJ/WebStorm to answer or improve.

Comment: That view is not consistent with the close vote reviewing process, in which voting to close questions that don't meet the guidelines is what we're asked to do.   The close vote queue presented the question to me as "This question is flagged for closure.  Does it meet the on-topic guidelines?"   I assessed it as being opinion based, so voted for closure.  Upon finding that I failed an audit for that decision, I came here to calibrate my understanding.    The sense I'm taking away is that my understanding of what to vote for closure is pretty reasonable :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade What made you think this particular question was "almost nothing to do with programming" and "almost entirely opinion based"?

Comment: The element of the original question that made it appear to me to be too broad and opinion-based is "what are the biggest distinctions between WebStorm && IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition for the Dart workflow?".   This is a broad qualitative question.